# how to get magento admin users from magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-controller

I want to get magento admin users and assign them a mobile number, from each particular agent panel, agent can able make a call from that number.

Answer (score 1):

To get Users

```
<?php
//By Username get admin User's Details
$username = 'admin';
$user_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getData();
var_dump($user_data);

//By Username get admin User's Role Details
$username = 'admin';
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username',$username)->getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);

//By ID get admin User's Details
$id = 1;
$user_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getData();
var_dump($user_data);


//By ID get admin User's Role Details
$id = 1;
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id)->getRole()->getData();
var_dump($role_data);
```

To change or update user details, you can follow the given code

```
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
        $user->setIsActive(1)
        ->save();
```

in the above code, you can use your field name which you want to update